# Extract file in resource then save to file in C++

Tags: c++, file, resources

i'm new to C++ so hope everyone can help me solved this problem, i want extract file in resource then save to file in C++.

Thank all

Comment: I attach a DLL in resource, i want extract it to temp folder then call it

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/XResFilePt1.aspx